# Typescript generics constraints

Tags: typescript

Apologies for the vague title but I have no idea how to word this question succinctly!

I am trying to implement a class:

`class Stream<Template<T,K,I>>`

I know this is not syntactically correct. So far I have...

```
class Stream<T extends object, K, I extends string> {
  constructor(ledger: Ledger, template: Template<T, K, I>) {
    this.ledger = ledger;
    this.stream = ledger.streamQuery(template);
  }

  private ledger: Ledger;
  private stream: DamlStream<T, K, I, readonly CreateEvent<T, K, I>[]>;
...
```

What I am trying to do is make a generic Stream such that a stream can be defined as:

`stream: Stream<Record>`

where `Record` is a `Template<T,K,I>`.

I DO NOT want to have the class definition as `Stream<T,K,I>` because the `T` `K` and `I` of the `Record` are nasty-looking, generated hash strings. This would look ugly.

TLDR:
I want to be able to define a stream as `stream: Stream<Record>`, not `stream: Stream<RecordT, RecordK, RecordI>`

Please advise if you have something constructive to say!

Cheers

EDIT: (More clarification)

I would like to instantiate the Stream class with the constructor like this: `stream = new Stream(ledger, StorageRecord)`. Here `StorageRecord` is a type generated from the backend and is of type `Template<T,K,I>` where `K`, `T` and `I` sometimes have very long ugly names.

The problem is when I want to have define a `Stream` class member as `stream: Stream<...>`.

I want to just put `Stream<StorageRecord>`, for example.

I can't define `Stream` as `class Stream<T>` because `ledger.streamQuery` requires a `Template` as an argument.

I can't define `Stream` as `class Stream<T extends Template>` because `Template` is itself generic.

I need to keep track of `T`, `K` and `I` because they are needed in the class too.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would use an instantiate this class? What I'm trying to figure out is where `T, K, I` come from, because they have to be defined and passed to `Template` somewhere.

Comment: If your class is generic over a parameter, you need to make it generic. Perhaps you don't need to worry about the aesthetics, because the type arguments don't need to be manually provided?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by using the conditional `infer` syntax, the first generic should extend `Template` in the most generic way and then you can have additional generics that just infer data from that so that you can use it later in the class.

```
class Stream<Templ extends Template<any,any,any>, 
             T extends object=(Templ extends Template<infer A,any,any> ? A : never), 
             K extends  any  =(Templ extends Template<any,infer A,any> ? A : never),
             I extends string=(Templ extends Template<any,any,infer A> ? A : never)
             > {
    constructor(ledger: Ledger, template: Templ) {
        this.ledger = ledger;
        this.stream = ledger.streamQuery(template);
    }

    private ledger: Ledger;
    private stream: DamlStream<T, K, I, readonly CreateEvent<T, K, I>[]>;
}
```

This way `Stream< StorageRecord>` should infer the inner arguments properly. Note that `Stream<StorageRecord, {}, 0, "hi">` would also technically be valid and may break stuff so to have more rigorous code you would have to do something like this:

```
type _inferT<Templ extends Template<any,any,any>> = Templ extends Template<infer A,any,any> ? A : never
type _inferK<Templ extends Template<any,any,any>> =(Templ extends Template<any,infer A,any> ? A : never)
type _inferI<Templ extends Template<any,any,any>> = (Templ extends Template<any,any,infer A> ? A : never)
class Stream<Templ extends Template<any,any,any>> {
    constructor(ledger: Ledger, template: Templ) {
        this.ledger = ledger;
        this.stream = ledger.streamQuery(template);
    }

    private ledger: Ledger;
    private stream: DamlStream<_inferT<Templ>, _inferK<Templ>, _inferI<Templ>, readonly CreateEvent<_inferT<Templ>, _inferK<Templ>, _inferI<Templ>>[]>;
}
```

But this gets really annoying quite quickly which is why I suggested putting the short hands in the class generics first, it gives you faster references to the correct type.

Comment: No, unfortunately I need T,K and I for other internal types too! I want to know if T,K and I can be inferred from the template.

Comment: ahh, ok that gets a little more interesting then, so you want `Stream<StorageRecord>` to be able to grab the generics imbedded into `StorageRecord` automatically, yes that can be done let me put together...

Comment: Let me have a look/test and I'll let you know! Thanks @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work:                                                                                 `Type 'TransportationRecord' does not satisfy the constraint 'Template<any, any, any>'.
  Type 'TransportationRecord' is missing the following properties from type 'Template<any, any, any>': templateId, keyDecoder, Archive, decoderts(2344)` I think this is because the imported `TransportationRecord` sometimes acts as a `type`, and sometimes as a `namespace` (Template). I am very confused! From the same import it acts in different ways :'(((

Comment: you did say "Here `StorageRecord` is a type generated from the backend and **is of type `Template<T,K,I>`**" so if your type isn't actually assignable to `Template<any,any,any>` then that is not my problem to fix, are you sure you are using the type corresponding to a valid value passed to the second argument to the constructor? keep in mind `typeof` can be used to grab the type of a value if you have the value accessible.

Comment: you can also use [`import type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#importing-types) to explicitly only import the type (and alias it to a different name maybe) so you can be sure you aren't working with the value or namespace in a type context.

Comment: Yes i think you touched on the problem! Here is what VSCode says when I hover over the import of the record: `(alias) type TransportationRecord = {
    transporter: string;
    productOwner: string;
    productInfo: Types.ProductInfo;
    startEvent: Types.Event;
    endEvent: Types.Event;
}
(alias) namespace TransportationRecord
(alias) const TransportationRecord: damlTypes.Template<TransportationRecord, undefined, "827c178267266bb80711c560783b5391b5a3a45035176e251689366b6ce2ee85:Records:TransportationRecord"> & {
    ...;
}
import TransportationRecord`

Comment: generated file: `export declare type TransportationRecord = {
    transporter: damlTypes.Party;
    productOwner: damlTypes.Party;
    productInfo: Types.ProductInfo;
    startEvent: Types.Event;
    endEvent: Types.Event;
};
export declare const TransportationRecord: damlTypes.Template<TransportationRecord, undefined, '827c178267266bb80711c560783b5391b5a3a45035176e251689366b6ce2ee85:Records:TransportationRecord'> & {
    Archive: damlTypes.Choice<TransportationRecord, pkgd14e08374fc7197d6a0de468c968ae8ba3aadbf9315476fd39071831f5923662.DA.Internal.Template.Archive, {}, undefined>;
};`

Comment: How can I just import the `const`...?

Comment: I would probably do `import {a} from ...` and `import type {a as RESERVED_NAME} from ...` so you have the const normally (it will also be namespace and type) and the type as a separate name.

Comment: Thanks. Still doesn't work. I would discuss in chat but don't have the 'rep' for it. And the fact that I cannot properly format code in the stackoverflow comments doesn't help... I think that the problem is that the `Template<....>` version of the Record might actually be a `const`. It is the `type` that doesn't work with your solution. Apologies if I have been unclear. Thanks for your help. @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen

Comment: Fixed with `stream: Stream<typeof TransportationRecord>`